# Activity Recognition Client battery comsumption

Tags: android, activity-recognition

I wish to use for my app [ActivityRecognitionClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionClient), and I wish it will run always in the background. But how much battery actually it consume and what is the best interval for battery optimization? 
In the reference it only says

"*Larger values will result in fewer activity detections while improving battery life. Smaller values will result in more frequent activity detections but will consume more power since the device must be woken up more frequently*"

Can you tell me in real life how much it will consume per refresh rate?

Comment: Make an experiment) Write a small app and use if for couple of days.

Comment: This is the trivial solution. But every day I use different amount of battery. (Some days play games and some not). I need clean laboratory environment with another phone. Hence I asked the question here to save me getting another phone and wasting many days.

Comment: There is a battery usage analysis app in settings of every android phone. So you can check how much battery was used by each app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is nearly impossible to correctly answer this question because the answer is a resounding "it depends."

The amount of battery power that a particular action will consume on a phone is difficult to determine because there are a ton of different factors that play into it.

First, Android attempts to batch many types of requests such as this together, so if 10 different apps wants to detect updates ever 5 minutes, it will only do it once every 5 minutes instead of 10 times every 5 minutes. Which app and which action is responsible for that?

Second, activity detection relies on whatever sensors (and models of sensors) are available on the device. Different devices have different GPS chips, accelerometer chips, etc. Some devices may not have all of those types of sensors as well. These all change the amount of energy activity recognition will consume.

These are just a few of the reasons it is difficult to determine how much energy an update will consume.

The answer for "how often should I request updates" is "as infrequently as your app can tolerate." Think about your use case and the general statement that more frequent updates will consume more power, and make the appropriate decision from there.